# PostGIS layers as WMS service with QGIS Server

Tags: postgis, wms, qgis-server

I have QGIS, PostGIS and QGIS Server running under Windows 7.

When I make a QGIS project with different Postgis layers and save the project under my QGIS Server path to publish it as an WMS service, i can see no layers at all.
The qgis2web plugin for example also shows me only the map legend but no map at all.
My WMS connection has also only the project name in it, no layers to select.
My KBS is set correct, thats not the problem i think.

Is it not possible to make a QGIS Project with PostGIS data in it, save it, and then publish it as a WMS service?

Comment: qgis2web has only been tested with Geoserver WMSes, not QGIS Server (or eg MapServer). I'd therefore not use qgis2web as evidence that it's not working.

Comment: Thats right, but i also don't see any layers when i connect with Autocad Map 3D to the WMS service.